# Waiting for the dTypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm writing a discord bot using the `discord.js` v12.2.0 library and I get this error:

> Waiting for the dTypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

This is my code:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { VultrexDB } = require("vultrex.db");
const messageData = new VultrexDB({
    name: "messages"
})

module.exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.member;
    const messages = messageData.get(`${message.guild.id}-${member.id}`, 0);

    message.chanel.send(new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("E67E22")
        .setAuthor(`Data | ${member.user.username}`, member.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .addField("Messages Sent:", messages, true)
    );
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "messages",
    description: "view the amount of messages sent by a member"
}

module.exports.requirements = {
    clientPerms: ["EMBED_LINKS"],
    userPerms: [],
    ownerOnly: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should learn to debug especially since this error practically tells you the answer. Did it tell you which line? If so there;s your answer but incase it didnt:

1. Tells you invalid arg, this means you called a function (including a new class), and the arguments you passed in were invalid
2. Argument was undefined

`new VultrexDB`, `message.mentions.members.first`, `message.mentions.members.cache.get`,
`messageData.get`, `new MessageEmbed`,
`setColor`, `setAuthor`, `addField`

you can rule out `MessageEmbed and`message.mentions.members.first`since they don't require any arguments,`setColor`,`setAuthor`, and`addField` all are giving arguments

that leaves `new VultrexDB`, `message.mentions.members.cache.get` and `messageData.get`

for `message.mentions.members.cache.get`, it only requires one argument, the id, and you pass it by `args[0]`, so to check if this is the problem just check if you have args

for `new VultrexDB` and `messageData.get`, those are VultrexDB based and idk it, so just look at a guide or the documentation if they have one.